# Sanitize branch name to avoid problems with website name

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure Devops Release pipeline to automatically publish Pull Requests to test domain `branchname.blablabla.com`

[image: Deployment process website name parameter]

Everything works fine, but sometimes branch name contains dot . and deployment task fails due to 4th level domain name like `branch.name.blablabla.com`

Is there a way to remove illegal characters from *$(Build.SourceBranchName)* before it binds to PARAMETERS_WEBSITENAME?

Comment: May I know how's the status of this after the weekend? Does below script can help to achieve what you want? Don't hesitate to share your comment if you still has puzzle with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one additional task before using it in `website name`, to remove dot from the branch name. For example, you can add [Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) task to run one shell script:

```
a="$(echo $(Build.SourceBranchName) | tr -d .)"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BranchName]$a"
```

In this script, it firstly remove dot `.` from `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` value. Then create one new variable `BranchName` and assign the modified value to it.

Now, in your next task, you can call this modified value by using `$(BranchName)`.

[image]

Comment: The thing is that binding of input parameters happens before any task in a stage. I tried to add another stage but could not pass updated variables to the next stage.

Comment: @irriss, So, you mean the website name modified and the website deployed does not exists in one stage? Does this happen in release pipeline with UI? If yes, I could share you one script to make the new website name available for whole pipeline.

Comment: Everything is in one stage. What I mean is that pipleline parameter "Website Name" is resolved first and task IIS Web App Deploy always uses orginial value. Whatever I do in tasks does not change "Website Name" value passed to IIS Web App Deploy. https://imgur.com/SMEuS53

Comment: @irriss, This is because in that task, you are still calling our environment variable which can not be **modified and override** manually. You can see in my above script, I stored the modified branch name into new variable **BranchName**. Then call it by using **$(BranchName)**

Comment: Website Name in IIS Web App Deploy task is linked to pipeline parameter with same name. Do you suggest that I unlink it and then replace with updated variable $(BranchName)?

Comment: @irriss. Yeap. You need replace that with this new variable $(BranchName) which contains the modified value. Because environment variable are read-only. What we can do is get its value, do some changes and store it into one new variable.